# Setting a NetCDF dimension value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a variable with 4 dimensions, and I want to set 3 of these equal to fixed values so only one is changing (i.e. I can get a 2D graph representation of the variable) - however I can't find a way to do this with scipy and numpy. I'm reluctant to install NetCDF4 (I'm only on work experience - I learnt python last week so I'm very new to this).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`NetCDF4` lets you designate one dimension as variable so it can organize the data file layout in a convenient way.  You can only add data to the end of a file.  Any other changes require rewriting the file, or at least large chunks of it.  In addition a lot of NetCDF4 data has a natural 'growth' dimension, e.g spatial fixed sample points, but growing over time.

`numpy` arrays don't have such an option, and usually don't need it.  If you need to add data to an array, you use `concatenate` to create a new array, one that contains both the old data and the new.  Or rather it joins all the elements, without an 'old' v 'new' distinction.  `np.concatenate` is compiled and thus reasonably fast.  I believe it acts by creating new empty array of the right size, and copying over the data from the inputs.

There is a `np.append`, but it really is just a front end to `concatenate`.  For a one time addition to an array it is fine, but new users often misuse it by putting it in a loop, adding items one by one to an array.

A common `numpy` idiom for constructing an array is to append the pieces to a list, and passing that list to `np.array` at the end.  Python `list` has an efficient append method.  Such a list could also be passed to `np.concatenate`.

Another common approach is to initialize a large enough empty array, and then insert subarrays along the appropriate dimension.

Creating an array incrementally is a common SO numpy question.